# How to reduce database bloat for faster upgrading?

Tags: database, upgrade, performance

In order to speed up slow upgrades, experienced folk ([1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16425/how-can-i-monitor-the-progress-of-a-slow-upgrade)
[2](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/16426/speeding-up-a-slow-upgrade)) recommend reducing the size of the database to facilitate testing.

What is the best way to declutter the database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Best to review the tables which are largest in your DB, and also identify which queries during the upgrade take the longest. This is a chicken-and-egg problem, which means you might review the tables you "lighten" as you work through the upgrade process.

Here's something I was using a few years ago on fairly heavy DB. This would exclude data in those tables from being tested on upgrade, but that was an acceptable tradeoff to test the core upgrade.

**WARNING - this SQL will destroy data in the DB you execute it against.**

```
-- Trim a CiviCRM DB by stripping out the enormous amount of data
-- stored in some tables, especially the ones relating to mailing.
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_cache;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_log;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_bounce;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_delivered;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_forward;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_opened;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_reply;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_trackable_url_open;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_unsubscribe;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_event_queue;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_recipients;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_mailing_spool;
TRUNCATE TABLE civicrm_subscription_history;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

A couple of automated scripts would use the above to reduce a copy of the live DB to a more workable upgrade dataset, then test the upgrade against this reduced DB.

Another set of DB tables you might remove is those prefixed `log_*`. The ARCHIVE table format they use by default has on-the-fly compression, and every DB update will trigger a duplicate query against log. This means you run double the number of DB updates, one of which will also require some compression. [Disabling CiviCRM's trigger logging](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/7504/how-to-migrate-database-without-logs) feature should then reduce the size of the database and the amount of work it does for each change.